# adding a http request header with Dictionary

Tags: c#, pact

Im trying to add http request header like below

```
 Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            {"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
                            {"CD-SystemId" , Common.CommonValues._systemId}
                        },
```

But I'm thrown,

```
"message": "No interaction found for POST 
/SubscriberManagement/CreateSubscriber",
"interaction_diffs": [
  {
  "description": "Create subscriber",
  "provider_state": "A session id",
  "headers": {
    "CD-SystemId": {
      "EXPECTED": "1ce731f0-33a6-4caf-b535-586fcf3bda60",
      "ACTUAL": "<key not found>"
    }
  }
```

I need to just add the above 2 json content as headers.

Comment: Hi! Your question seems unclear to me, what is the problem you are facing? Also add [mcve], I don't see any request here.

Comment: Have you tried this : request.Headers["My-Custom-Header"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            {"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
                            {"CD-SystemId" , Common.CommonValues._systemId}
                        }

Comment: @WaleedNaveed : thanks. but request is not recognised.

Comment: I am not sure, but i think you can't pass dictionary in the header, you have to pass such member of dictionary explicitly@ Sriyad

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add header value in Mock side. I mean you can try adding below values in mock code.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"/SubscriberManagement/CreateSubscriber");
request.Headers.Add("CD-SystemId", "1ce731f0-33a6-4caf-b535-586fcf3bda60");
```